# Rendering Images to razor view Cshtml. Angular issues

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

"allitems" contains all items for a category that is selected in a combobox. That part of the code working properly.

I have images saved in a database as binary data for each item. When an item is displayed then the image of the item shall be rendered. For doing this I have to save item's ID in ASP .Net controller before rendering, because the "RenderImage" needs the Item's ID. This is done by calling "saveItemId" in AngularJS controller.

But the rendering of the images are very unpredictable. "saveItemId" is called repeatedly but not RenderImage.

There is no problem calling methods/saving ID in AngularJS controller or in ASP .Net MVC controller.

```
<div dir-paginate="r in allitems | filter:q | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage" ng-init ='saveItemId(r.ID)' class="ag-fresh">
<div style="float:left">
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div style="width:200px;">
            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                <div class="single-products">
                    <div class="productinfo text-center">
                        <img src="@Url.Action("RenderImage")" height="84" width="84"/>
                        <br/>
                            <h>{{r.Price}}</h>
                            <p>{{r.Name}}</p>
                            <button class="btn btn-default add-to-cart" ng-click="AddToCart(r.ID)">Add to cart</button>
                            {{successTextAlert}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. its seems that RenderImage is a js variable in the controller scope. if its so, its need to be call with brackets, like `{{RenderImage}}`
2. Try using `'ng-src'` instead `'src'` attribute, for the img element as described at 
   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc#!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. RenderImage is a function in ASP .Net controller. The reason why I use it is the following:                                                         I have already tried with these whitout any success. The "internalImage" is an array of bytes:                                                                                   <img ng-src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{r.InternalImage}}"/>
<img ng-src="data:image/jpg,{{r.InternalImage}}"/>

Answer (score 0):

This works properly:
`<img ng-src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{arrayBufferToBase64(r.InternalImage)}}" height="84" width="84"/>`
I Added arrayBufferToBase64 to the angular controller.